# close window from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to close the current window from javascript without any events like onclick or something else..

```
   <script>
   window.close();
   </script>
```

The above doesnt seems top work..

Edit:
      i am opening a child window from a parent window and after some operation i want to close the child window and `window.close();` doesnt seem to work

Thanks..

Comment: without events? seriously? then the page will close as soon as its opened. isn't it?

Comment: using it after this "some operation"

Comment: yes but is has few operations performed before it closes..

Comment: it's just about 
window.close(); doesnt seem to work

so self.close () works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when do you want it to trigger? It will need some kind of event to trigger it, either on the document ready (if you want to close it immediately after opening it), or on some other event (a timer, a click, whatever).

If you explain what you want to happen, it's probably easy to solve.

EDIT: Sorry, just checked it in FireBug, and Oded is correct. FireBug says scripts are not allowed to close windows that where not opened by script. But if it where, it should work...

EDIT2: I used this code to open a new window:

```
$(function(){
    window.open('/test2.html','test2','width=300,height=200');
});
```

And then the following in the newly opened window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        window.close();
    });
    </script>
    test
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me.

EDIT3: Ripping out the jQuery and running the script in the body with no document ready checking also worked, but that might fail if you want to do anything other than closing the window. Any kind of document ready checking should work though. I just used jQuery because it's simple... :)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that `window.close()` **has** to be within a function, even an anonymous one -- just like that it wouldn't work. Try putting it in a function and calling it.